# iOS 9.3 ipad a delay between adding a class and getting up-to-date value

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I wrote a multi-level menu with edge detection wherein at the page load event I loop over all the submenus and if a submenu offset left exceeds the browser width I add a class ".edge" to it which will display it on the left.

```
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.submenu.edge {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

Well, it works fine with all the browsers that I tested on except iOS 9.3 and that because there is a delay between adding the class and the browser updating the offset left.

let me explain if I do this.

```
console.log( $submenu.offset().left );
```

if the submenu left offset is 1000 it will print 1000 in the console.

```
$submenu.addClass('edge');
console.log( $submenu.offset().left );
```

if the submenu width is 200 and the container of the submenu is 200 this will print 600 in the console. the thing is with ios 9.3 iPad safari (probably even chrome) it will still print 1000.

but if I want to get 600 I should do something along the way

```
$submenu.addClass('edge');

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log( $submenu.offset().left );
}, 2000);
```

Is there anything I could do to get the right value immediately after adding the class or I should look for alternative solution.

Comment: Do you have to wait 2 full seconds? Have you tried it with a lower number, or no number at all? Alternatively, you might try forcing a browser layout via something here: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: @TopherFangio more like 700ms to get the desired effect, but there could be a few of those submenus so I should wait 700ms between each one those.  because those submenus could be nested so I should wait until a get the right value.

I try some of those functions that force the layout but got nowhere.